# Play Store App icon pixelated

Tags: android, google-play

Play Store requires a "High res icon", which is 512x512.

For some reason, it looks pixelated on the store listing, despite being 512x512 (png).

The image is fine when I open it on my PC, just not on store.
Anyone knows what's going on?

Edit: Image (Smart Picks is my app)

[image]

Comment: can you share  a screen shot also on what phone?

Comment: Your icon is respecting the design guidelines ? It has to have padding and stuff not only a 512x512 pixel size . https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons

Comment: Is this about your app having a pixelated icon or just the Google play website having undesired output of your icon?

Comment: Use this icon for maximum compliance: https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/google-play - It has all DPI levels covered in multiple sizes and B/W/G.

Comment: Your image looks like a jpg, not by any chance a jpg saved as png? (note converting doesn't help in this case)

Comment: Also google maps and fitness thingy looks blurry as well, seems like your screenshot is not the best quality

Comment: @MathijsSegers it's png

Comment: Also note that there is probably a copyright on Dota 2 logo.

Comment: @skypower did you find the reason why this happens? I've seen this before but so far can't figure out why.

Comment: @skypower did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Changer Ah it's been 4 years since then. I don't remember how I fixed it and also can't find it due to a computer change unfortunately. But make sure you do everything correct because I don't remember getting stuck there.

Comment: @Enzokie Man I just saw your comment and I would like to say that I was devastated by getting the app rejected due to the impersonation policy because of the logo! Notice that they didn't tell me why it was getting rejected; I fixed it randomly!